# Get row element form row.clicked event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Table from Bootstrap Vue, and I'm trying to display row details when clicking on a row.

I used `row-clicked` event as the doc said, but I don't find any row details with a `toggleDetails` method.
So I don't even know how to open it and where `toggleDetails` come from.

There is a way to open this details row with `row.clicked` event ?

Or should I use another method to do this ?

Do you have some clues ?

**EDIT**

There is some code to illustrate a bit more my problem, there is my table with the details row.

```xml
<b-table
  v-if="items"
  :items="items"
  :fields="fields"
  show-empty
  striped
  hover
  responsive
  empty-text="There is no messages to show"
  class="col-sm-12 col-md-10"
  @row-clicked="test"
>
  <template
    slot="message"
    slot-scope="row"
  >
    {{ row.item.message }}
  </template>
  <template
    slot="row-details"
    slot-scope="row"
  >
    <code>{{ row.item.message }}</code>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

You can see the `row.clicked` event I use on the table, and then my methods where I'm trying to open the row details. It's a simple method with some console.log

```js
methods: {
  test(item, index, event) {
    console.log(item, index, event);
  },
},
```

Comment: Show more code so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: @skribe I have added some code to illustrate.

Comment: untagging D because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the D programming language...

Comment: Yes nice catch, this was a fail tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do is to place somewhere in your "base" row (probably in a row cell called *actions*) a button that calls the `toggleDetails` function for this specific row.

The code for this button and the details row should be like this:

```xml
<template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
    <!-- We use @click.stop here to prevent a 'row-clicked' event from also happening -->
    <b-button size="sm" @click.stop="row.toggleDetails">
        {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Details
    </b-button>
</template>
<template slot="row-details" slot-scope="row">
    <!-- Your row details' content here -->
</template>
```

You can find more examples and explanations in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#row-details-support)

If you want to show the row details by clicking anywhere in the row, firstly you should add a `_showDetails` variable to each item object:

```js
items: [
    { foo: true, bar: 40, _showDetails: false },
    ...
    { foo: true, bar: 100, _showDetails: false }
]
```

Then you just have to add the proper functionality for the row-clicked event:

```xml
<b-table @row-clicked="onRowClicked" ...></b-table>
```

And in your component methods:

```js
methods: {
    onRowClicked (item, index, event) {
        item._showDetails = !item._showDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know I can trigger the details opening with a button as you write. But I trying to open this row details when I click anywhere on a row.

Comment: I edited my post to also answer your specific problem.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see what I need to do, I will try it, thanks

Comment: Please make sure to add the "_showDetails" variable on each item object when created, else beware the Vue reactivity caveats https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Yes that is what I did, this is working well, thanks

Comment: What version of BV is this solution for? It's not working for me with v2.2.

Comment: If you're using an ajax call to fetch the data, you need to do something like this, assuming `data` contains the response data:
`setRowData: function (data) {data.forEach(e => e._showDetails = false); this.items = data; }`

Comment: this is working well, thanks.